# How to write if else statement in Linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

How to write the following if-else condition in Linear Programming?
If $a > b$ then
    $c = d$
else
    $c = e$

$d$, $e$ are variables. How can we write a linear program without multiplying d and e with binary variables? But we can use binary variables.

$a,b,c,d,e > 0$

Comment: In general this can not be done in a pure continuous LP. You need binary variables to overcome the non-convexity in this construct. Some very special cases may not need binary variables.

Comment: We can use binary variables but I don't want to multiply those binary variables with d or e because they too are variables in my problem. If we multiply binary variables with d or e the problem will lose linearity.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This can not be formulated as a linear programming problem. We need extra binary variables and end up with a MIP.

First we do:

$$ a > b \Longleftrightarrow \delta = 1$$

This can be formulated as:
$$\begin{align}
   &a \ge b + 0.001 - M(1-\delta)\\
   &a \le b + M\delta\\
   &\delta \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}$$
(in practice I would drop the $0.001$ term).

Next we do:
$$\begin{align}
   &\delta=1 \Longrightarrow c=d\\
   &\delta=0 \Longrightarrow c=e
\end{align}$$
This can be written as:
$$\begin{align}
   & d-M(1-\delta)\le c \le d + M(1-\delta)\\
   & e-M\delta\le c \le e + M\delta\\
\end{align}$$

Many modern MIP solvers have indicator constraints. This can make things easier as one can write implications directly without big-M constraints.

Comment: @Erwin....how can we formulate, If a = b then c = d else c = e ?

Comment: In a similar way. Use something like $ \delta = 0 \implies a=b, c=d$ and $ \delta = 0 \implies a \ne b, c=e$.

Comment: I was expecting something more like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3593827/how-to-write-if-else-statement-in-mixed-integer-programming)