# How to write if else statement in Mixed Integer Programming?

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I posted a similar question earlier [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2500415/how-to-write-if-else-statement-in-linear-programming)

How to write the following if-else condition in Linear/MI Programming?
If $a = b$ then
    $c = d$
else
    $c = e$

$a,b,c,d,e$ all are variables. How can we write a linear program without multiplying d and e with binary variables? But we can use binary variables.

Comment: What kind of variables?

Comment: real numbers. Doesn't have to be integers?

Comment: In your [motivating question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3593506/how-to-write-a-mixed-integer-program-for-a-streak), $(c,d,e)=(x,1,-1)$, right?

Comment: You are right, but I want to generalize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [this question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/33/in-an-integer-program-how-i-can-force-a-binary-variable-to-equal-1-if-some-cond/2632#2632), you need some tolerance $\delta>0$, bounds $[L_1,U_1]$ on $a-b$, bounds $[L_2,U_2]$ on $c-d$, and bounds $[L_3,U_3]$ on $c-e$.

Introduce three binary variables $y^-$, $y$, and $y^+$ and big-M constraints:
$$
y^- + y + y^+ = 1\\
L_1 y^- + 0y + \delta y^+
\le a- b \le
-\delta y^- + 0y + U_1 y^+\\
L_2(1-y) \le c - d \le U_2(1-y)\\
L_3 y \le c - e \le U_3 y
$$