# How to write if statement for 3 dimensional problem linear programming

Tags: mixed-integer-programming

I have a problem regarding formulating the following with math notation. My goal is that if shop i’s arrival time is lower than all the other shop’s arrival times, then shop i must be allocated to the palletspace with the lowest distance (to obtain this, the solution would choose the port accordingly, I imagine)

My parameters are:

1. SL denoting shop labels (i)
2. PL denoting port labels (j)
3. PSL denoting palletspace labels (l)
4. A_i denoting the arrival times for a shop to a port (same no matter which port)
5. D_jl denoting the distance from port j to palletspace l
6. S =range(0, len(SL)
7. P =range(0, len(PL)
8. PS =range(0, len(PSL)

Variables:
x_ijl = 1 if shop i is using pallet space l through port j
y_ij = 1 if shop i is using port j

Now for the constraint I imagine it could be formulated as such:
If A_i <= A_k, forall i in S, forall k in S Then x_ijl must be assigned to the pallet space with the lowest distance which isn’t already used by another shop (I have a constraint which ensures that one palletspace can’t be used by another).

So maybe something like:
If A_i <= A_k, then x_ijl**distance_jl <= x_kjl*distance_jl

I don’t know guys, I’ve never wrote a linear program for this kind of if statement with multiple indexes…

I read this stack exchange post but I can’t adapt it to my problem…
[How to write if else statement in Linear programming?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2500415/how-to-write-if-else-statement-in-linear-programming?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Is $A_i$ a decision variable or an input parameter?

Comment: Hi @RobPratt. A_i is an input parameter containing an array as long as SL. For instance, 1, 4, 3, 2 meaning shop_1 should have the lowest distance palletspace, shop_4 should have the second lowest distance palletspace, shop_3 should have the third lowest distance palletspace and so on. Thanks for asking for clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the arrival times are known, you don't need anything complicated.  For $r\in\{1,\dots,|SL|\}$, let $i_r$ be the index of the shop with the $r$th lowest arrival time.  In your example, $(i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4)=(1,4,3,2)$.

The desired constraints are
$$\sum_{j,l} d_{jl} x_{i_rjl} \le \sum_{j,l} d_{jl} x_{i_{r+1}jl} \quad \text{for all $r\in\{1,\dots,|SL|-1\}$}.$$
Note that this formulation assumes that
$$\sum_{j,l} x_{ijl} = 1 \quad \text{for all $i$}.$$
That is, each shop is assigned to exactly one port and pallet space.

Comment: Hi @RobPratt, the problem I face is that i is not the index of the shop with the lowest arrival time. It is merely the shop i. So for the constraint to work, I would imagine I need to sort the shops with respect to their arrival times. 

In Python I would do this as: sorted_shop_indexes = sorted(range(len(arrival_times)), key=lambda i: arrival_times[i]) and then have a new decision variable, q, iterate over this list. So q(sorted_shop_indexes, ports, pallet spaces)

Comment: Hi @RobPratt, sorry for the late reply. Thanks for your fast adjustment of the constraint. The assumption is not met as palletspaces can’t accommodate the entire demand of a shop. So a shop would be using multiple palletspaces, but only one port. But maybe that can be resolved by looping over l as well. So, for all sorted_retailer, for all palletspaces, the total distance for shop i picking from palletspace l through port j, should be less than or equal to the distance of the next shop. I will try to implement this

Comment: I rearranged the retailer list with respect to arrival times. Indeed, we can just iterate of the length of retailers. I did this as so (your constraint):

    model.arrivalkortestdistance=pyomo.ConstraintList()
    for i in range(1, len(model.retailer_labels)):
        model.arrivalkortestdistance.add(expr=sum(model.distance_matrix[j][l]*model.x[i-1,j,l] for j in model.loading_ports for l in model.palletspaces)
<=
sum(model.distance_matrix[j][l]*model.x[i,j,l] for j in model.loading_ports for l in model.palletspaces))